# Svelte i18n reset language on page change

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have a Svelte app using `svelte-i18n` and `svelte-router-spa`

I loaded my local in `app.svelte`like this

```
  register('en', () => import('./i18n/en.json'));
  register('fr', () => import('./i18n/fr.json'));
  register('it', () => import('./i18n/it.json'));

  init({
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    initialLocale: 'en',
    
  })?.catch((e: Error) => console.error(e));
```

Then I use a picker to select a local that do

```
  function setLanguage(lg?: Language) {
    locale.set(lg || Language.ENGLISH);
  }
```

Now, with this, the language change correctly, but when I navigate to a new route using for exemple

```
<a
  href={link}
  aria-label={$_('i18n.Button.MoreAbout', { default: 'More About', values: { subject } })}
>
  // ...
</a>
```

The local is always reset to English even I had change it.

Is it a default behavior and I need to reset the language on each page change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to you if and how you store language settings. E.g. the setting could be stored in [`sessionStorage` or `localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) on the client or a session object or database on the server.

Comment: ok so it s not built in, I need to do this ? ok. It seem pretty logical to me that if I set a language, it should remain in the app during the session unless I refresh the browser. Thank you